# MailMessage.From.DisplayName not behaving as expected with SmtpClient.Send()

Tags: email, .net-2.0, smtpclient

I am using the following code to send an email in .Net2.0.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("webmaster@mydomain.com", "webmaster@mydomain.com on behalf of someone else");
message.To.Add("someone@anotherdomain.com");
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = "some actual html here, not just a string literal"
message.Subject = "Alert email from www.mydomain.com";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("MySmtpClient.com", 25);
client.Send(message);
```

The problem I am experiencing is that when I check my email inbox, the from field of the email shows "webmaster@mydomain.com" and not "webmaster@mydomain.com on behalf of someone else", i.e. it's showing just the from email address instead of the DisplayName.

I've tried setting `message.ReplyTo` the same as I've set `message.From` but this seems to make no difference.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a Sender header.

For example:

```
message.Headers.Add( "Sender", "webmaster@mydomain.com" )
```

Comment: Actually you want the "somebody else" here, not the `webmaster@mydomain.com` address.